# If $f,g$ are any two functions with $f>g$, then there is a continuous function $h$ such that $f>h>g$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

Is the following claim true?

> Let $f,g : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ be *any* two functions such that $f>g$. Then there exists a continuous function $h:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f>h>g$.

I have no idea how to approach this, although the claim seems true to me. That being said, I am **not** interested in a proof, if the claim does happen to be correct ( I would like to find it for myself). However, I welcome counter examples, if the claim is false! I merely want to know whether or not the claim is true. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No! Note "any" is bold in the statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT**

Assuming $f,g$ continuous, consider $h(x) = (f(x)+g(x))/2$.

Otherwise, the claim is false. Consider for example,
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0 \\ 1, & x \ge 0 \end{cases}
\quad \text{ and } \quad g(x) = f(x) - \frac12
$$

then no such function $h$ exists which is continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: +1 for a simple example exploiting the usual "continuous functions can't climb that fast" principle

Comment: @qbert interesting formulation, never heard it before :)

Comment: Very nice counterexample. An interesting variant could be that either $f$ or $g$ are known to be continuous.

Answer (score 5):

No.  Let $f$ be the Dirichlet function and let $g=f-1/2.$