# If $f,g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are bounded with $g$ continuous and $f>g$, is there a continuous $h:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f>h>g$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

Is the following claim true:

> Let $f,g :[a,b]  \to  \mathbb{R}$ be bounded functions with $g$ continuous and $f>g$. Then there exists a continuous function $h: [a,b]  \to  \mathbb{R}$, such that $f>h>g$.

I am only interested in whether or not the claim is true or not, so please leave the proof to me if the claim is true. However, if the claim is false, I welcome counter examples!
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim is false. Consider any interval $[a,b]$ of non-zero length and define on it

$$g(x)=0$$

and

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } x \notin \mathbb Q \\
1, & \text{ if } x =0 \\
\frac1q, & \text{ if } x =\frac{p}q;p,q\in \mathbb Z, q>0, p\neq 0, \gcd(p,q)=1. \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: You should add that you are working on some closed interval containing $0$, say $[0,1]$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: That is not necessary. The definition is still valid even if $0\notin[a,b]$.

Comment: @TonyK You are right; one might just mention for clarity that this works as a counter-example also on compact sets/intervals and not just on $\mathbb R$ as a whole

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch The definition works IMO for any interval $[a,b]$ with non-zero length. If $0\notin [a,b]$, that clause is doing nothing. I included that extra clause only to avoid having to deal with $\gcd(0,q)$, which can be considered problematic.

Comment: @Ingix You are right aswell - it works on any closed interval with $>0$ length

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I added the info about the interval, it makes sure that this is understood as a counterexample on any possible interval. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 4):

You can take a similar example as in your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221463/if-f-g-are-any-two-functions-with-fg-then-there-is-a-continuous-function?rq=1):
[image]